# Select all columns except one in R sqldf package

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

Is there a way in R using the `sqldf` package to select all columns except one?

Comment: Requesting you to please provide sample data ```dput```and revised the question with details.as ```sqldf``` is for aggregating the data

Comment: Why is that needed for that kind of question? It is not specific data issue, but rather R package related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `sqldf` based on some query should return a data frame, where each DF column corresponds to one of the columns appearing in the select clause of your SQL query.  Consider the following example:

```
sql <- "SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE <some conditions>"
df <- sqldf(sql)
drop <- c("some_column")
df <- df[, !(names(df) %in% drop)]
```

Note in the above I am doing a `SELECT *` to fetch all columns in the table (what I assume is your use case).  I then subset off a column `some_column` from the resulting data frame.

Note that doing this from SQL directly generally is *not* possible.  That is, once you do `SELECT *`, the cat is out of the bag, and you end up with all columns.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But is there any way to avoid double columns after joining 2 tables? I mean if I have table ```a``` and table ```b``` and I am joining both them using same column ```customer_id``` in the final table I see two columns with same name ```customer_id```. Here is the code example ```data <- sqldf("selec a.*, b.* from a inner join b on (a.customer_id = b.customer_id)")```

Comment: No, there is no way to reliable way to do this, _unless_ the two columns named the same also coincidentally happen to have the same exact data.  In that case, you could, from R, arbitrarily just retain one of those two columns.  But, I don't recommend going down this road.  In general, you should _always_ explicitly list all columns you want to select.

Comment: I have answered your original question and you should not be giving follow-up questions here.

Comment: But if the question is rising from your answer I think this is the right place to ask additional questions. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Anyway, I think it was best place to answer that additional question, because it is related to same topic - excluding column when selecting data in SQL.

Comment: @GiedriusUrbonas It's a good question, at least from an `sqldf` point of view.  While a SQL result set can have duplicate column names, an R data frame _cannot_ have this, i.e. all column names must be unique.  You may play around with `sqldf` to see how you might handle this other challenge.

Answer (score 0):

**1) SQLite** Using the default SQLite backend, suppose we want to return the first 3 rows of all columns in `mtcars` except for the `cyl` column.  First create a comma separated string, `sel`, of all such column names and then use `fn$sqldf` to allow string interpolation referring to it in the SQL statement as `$sel`.  Add `verbose=TRUE` argument to `sqldf` if you want to see the SQL statement that was generated.

```
library(sqldf)

sel <- toString(setdiff(names(mtcars), "cyl"))
fn$sqldf("select $sel from mtcars limit 3")
```

giving:

```
   mpg disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 22.8  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

**2) H2** The H2 backend supports `alter table ... drop column ...` so we can write the following.  Since `alter` does not return anything we add a `select` which returns the altered table.

```
library(RH2)
library(sqldf)

sqldf(c("alter table mtcars drop column cyl", 
        "select * from mtcars limit 3"))
```